# handling a cookie ( delete)

Tags: javascript, html

Im using `chkArray.push($(this).val());` and  `document.cookie = 'ids='+chkArray;` within a `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function()` to store checkboxes values.

Then with a simple onclick function (AJAX) fecth products info from db and display in a div.

So far it is working well, but :

- How can I reset / Delete the {name:values} created with `document.cookie` after the onlick event ?

  I tried `document.cookie.length = 0; and chkArray.length = 0;` but it is not working.
- How to call the Array with the ids/values ? When I use the debugging console in chrome I can see under cookies Name(ids) and values ( XXX,XXX )
- If I want to store different values within the same function using `document.coolie`, will it replace the first pair (key:value) created from the checkboxes or added to it?

  `var x = 'abcd';`  `document.cookie = 'XName='+x;`

thanks

Comment: It will replace it, therefore delete your cookie by `document.cookie = 'ids=';`

Comment: Thanks! I can see now ids is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can reset all cookies with `document.cookie = ''`. You can empty an array with `chkArray = []`
- The cookie format is a key-value pair. For example, `document.cookie = 'ids=hi; name=Han'`. Now you have a cookie with two key-value pairs. `ids` and `name`.
- You have to loop yourself to get values out the array. You can use `array.join(',')`. You get a comma seperated list of ids

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can have a look at this plugin : [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to help you with your problems.

Comment: looks promising. i will give it a shot